# Dealing with android native crashes

Tags: android, firebase

Lately, we're experiencing native crashes spike in production. All those crashes are related to rendering UI and happened mostly on Android 12 and vendors like Samsung. Some of them from Play Console are:

```
[libhwui.so] SkCanvas::restore()
SIGSEGV
backtrace:
#00  pc 0x000000000026c9d8  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (SkCanvas::restore()+344)
#01  pc 0x000000000026c73c  /system/lib64/libhwui.so 
(android::SkiaCanvas::restore()+52)
#02  pc 0x00000000002008e0  /system/lib64/libhwui.so 
(android::CanvasJNI::restore(long)+56)
#03  pc 0x0000000000bef14c  /data/misc/apexdata/com.android.art/dalvik- 
cache/arm64/boot.oat (android.graphics.Canvas.restore+60)
```

or

```
[[vdso]] __kernel_rt_sigreturn
SIGSEGV
#00  pc 0x00000000001ac258  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so 
(art::ArtMethod::GetOatQuickMethodHeader(unsigned long)+40)
#01  pc 0x0000000000597864  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (void 
art::StackVisitor::WalkStack<(art::StackVisitor::CountTransitions)0>(bool)+516)
#02  pc 0x000000000059a514  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so 
(art::StackVisitor::GetVRegFromDebuggerShadowFrame(unsigned short, art::VRegKind, 
unsigned int*) const+284)
#03  pc 0x000000000059a314  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so 
(art::StackVisitor::GetVReg(art::ArtMethod*, unsigned short, art::VRegKind, unsigned 
int*, std::__1::optional<art::DexRegisterLocation>) const+76)
```

But we cannot understand their cause because neither Firebase Crashlytics nor other third parties can catch native crashes. We've googled everything and found nothing about how to get more data for the native crashes to find the cause. Maybe somebody has an experience with it and can share.